# Android: Copying a bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

A seemingly simple issue, I have an off-screen bitmap that I perform some transformations to (rotation, scaling, etc) and I'd like to store a copy of the bitmap prior to the transformations, such that in my View's `onDraw()`, I can display the transformed off-screen bitmap AND a smaller scaled version of the un-transformed bitmap as a thumbnail.

No problem writing the off-screen bitmap in `onDraw()`, but the copied 'preserved' bitmap is also being transformed.  Here is the code where I am making the copy of the bitmap, where mCanvas was created via `mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);`:

```
mPreservedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap);

// save the canvas
mCanvas.save();

// do some rotations, scaling
mCanvas.rotate(rotation, px, py);
mCanvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFocusX, scaleFocusY);

// draw the bitmaps to the screen
invalidate();

// restore the bitmap
mCanvas.restore();
```

In `onDraw()`, I have:

```
// draw the off-screen bitmap to the on-screen bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

// draw the preserved image, scaling it to a thumbnail first
canvas.drawBitmap(
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPreservedBitmap, (int) thumbWidth, (int) thumbHeight, true), 
null, 
thumbnailRectF, 
thumbCanvasPaint);
```

The thumbnail gets scaled to the appropriate size, but the bitmap that is being scaled down to thumbnail size is also rotated and scaled the exact same as mBitmap, which I don't want.  I've also tried the Bitmap.copy() method, but with the same results.  Any pointers/assitance/advice?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Is there anything else you're doing with mCanvas from the first snippet? It doesn't seem to actually do anything (rotate etc. only affects future operations, not the image itself). And why are you trying to copy the Bitmap in onDraw? By modifying the matrix of the canvas appropriately you should be able to scale the thumbnail on the fly.

Comment: I am using mCanvas at other points in the code to add completed shapes that the user has drawn to the off-screen bitmap.  I could indeed move the createScaledBitmap code out of onDraw, I just had it in there to test out the copying/scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution to this was to generate a copy of the canvas `Bitmap` PRIOR to it being scaled via:

```
mPreservedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), null, true);
```

Then, when the `Canvas` and the primary Bitmap is scaled, I can draw the non-scaled 'preserved' `Bitmap` to the `Canvas` in `onDraw()` via:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mPreservedBitmap, null, thumbnailRectF, thumbCanvasPaint);
```

Per Romain's comments above, I scale the preserved `Bitmap` off-screen to improve performance in `onDraw()`.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong :) First of all you should *never* keep a reference to a Canvas in a field. There is no guarantee whatsoever that the Canvas instance will be the same in two different calls to onDraw(). Your second problem is how you apply the transformations. You should apply them in onDraw():

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(rotation, px, py);
canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFocusX, scaleFocusY);
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
canvas.restore();

canvas.drawBitmap(
    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPreservedBitmap, (int) thumbWidth, (int) thumbHeight, true), null, thumbnailRectF, thumbCanvasPaint);
```

invalidate() is not a synchronous operation, your save()/restore() has no guarantee to work if done outside of onDraw().

Also do *not* call createScaledBitmap() from onDraw(), it is extremely expensive.

Comment: Thanks Romain.  I'll respond in two seperate comments.  If not for the field reference to the Canvas, which is used to access the off-screen mBitmap, how can I repeatedly write to the bitmap?  It's a drawing program that commits completed shapes to the off-screen bitmap as the user finishes them; as the user draws an in-progress shape, I call onDraw(), and once the shape is completed, it is cumulatively added to the mBitmap via mCanvas.  Should I be creating new Canvas references each time I wish to access the mBitmap `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);`?

Comment: In terms of performing the rotations and scaling in onDraw(), I originally had it set-up this way, but as I am calling onDraw as the user is drawing the current shape to the screen, things were very laggy having to rotate/scale the off-screen bitmap on the fly for n possible x/y pairs.  I have it set-up so that when the user is scaling, the entire off-screen bitmap gets redrawn on the off-screen, then flashed to the canvas in onDraw().  However, if the user has completed scaling and is drawing at scale, I am simply calling onDraw and using the already scaled off-screen bitmap.

Comment: As another follow-up, I've switched the code back so that the rotation and scaling is taking place in onDraw()... and the performance is pretty brutal.  When the user is in a state where the canvas is being rotated, and they are scaled in, as they draw and onDraw() gets called to show their progress, the lag/performance is boderline unusable.  I must be missing something.

Comment: If mCanvas is used to draw inside a Bitmap you can keep a reference to it. But you still cannot do a save()/restore() without drawing inside. It's useless./

Comment: Following up on this, I modelled it after the API demo FingerPaint.java, which does use a canvas in a field to draw to an off-screen bitmap. Any pointers on drawing Paths without using a canvas field?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment:

`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap)` returns an immutable bitmap. The documentation actually says that it might be the same object or use the same data.
You have to create a mutable bitmap, if you actually want to modify it, for example:

```
mPreservedBitmap = mBitmap;

// Create a new, empty bitmap with the original size.
// Since the image is going to be scaled, this might be to big or to small.
// Rotating might also require additional space (otherwise the corners will be cut off)
// Try calculating the proper size or play around with some other createBitmap Methods, just make sure to
// actually create a mutable bitmap, for example by using copy on an immutable bitmap.
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPreservedBitmap.getWidth(), mPreservedBitmap.getHeight(), mPreservedBitmap.getConfig());

mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

// do some rotations, scaling
mCanvas.rotate(rotation, px, py);
mCanvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFocusX, scaleFocusY);

// draw the original image to the canvas, applying the matrix modifications
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mPreservedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

And in onDraw:

```
// draw the off-screen bitmap to the on-screen bitmap
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

// draw the preserved image, scaling it to a thumbnail
canvas.drawBitmap(mPreservedBitmap, null, thumbnailRectF, thumbCanvasPaint);
```

Comment: Hmm, tried this, but the mPreservedBitmap is being set to the scaled version of mBitmap...